# Angular - dynamically set model property of object bound to radio button based on its state

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically set the model property of an object that is bound to the radio button, based on the state of the radio button.

To give some context, the page is creating a True/False question for a quiz, with a radio button for True and a radio button for False. I want the object property of the radio button to change based on its state. The reason for doing this is because the value is tied to `answer.is_correct` in the model, which is a boolean that indicates which answer is correct. If the question being asked is true, then the correct option should be True. But if the question being asked is false, then the correct option should be False.

As such, my requirements are:

1. If the True radio button is selected:

   - `answer.is_correct` should be **true** for True radio button
   - `answer.is_correct` should be **false** for False radio button
2. If the False radio button is selected:

   - `answer.is_correct` should be **false** for True radio button
   - `answer.is_correct` should be **true** for the False radio button

Here is a snippet of the current code, which is incorrect because if the user goes back to edit a previously created question (the form for creating and editing a question uses the same view), changing the correct answer from True to False does not set `answer.is_correct` to false for the True option. Instead, both True and False options have `answer.is_correct` as true, which is not want I want.

```
  <div ng-repeat="answer in question.answers" class="answer">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" ng-value="true" name="true_false_choice" ng-model="answer.is_correct">
      {{answer.choice}}
    </label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of investigating the problem, I figured out a solution. I added an `ng-change` directive to my radio input that would call a function in the controller to set the other radio button's value to false.

In the controller (note that I am using the `each` method in Underscore.js, but you can similarly iterate using a standard for loop):

```
$scope.setTrueFalseRadioState = function (answer) {
  _.each(question.answers, function (a) {
    if (a.choice !== answer.choice) {
      a.is_correct = false;
    }
  });
};
```

And I added the `ng-change` attribute to the input tag:

```
<input type="radio" name="true_false_choice" ng-model="answer.is_correct"
       ng-value="true" ng-change="setTrueFalseRadioState(answer)">
```

By doing this, the user can now go back to a question that was created earlier and edit the question (by changing the correct answer from True to False or vice versa), and the `is_correct` property will be updated appropriately based on the state of the radio button.

Answer (score 1):

```
I had a similar problem in AngularJS and here is the angular version of mannykary solution.
```

#### controller:

*using **controllerAs**, I use vm as a representation of the binding scope*

```
function setTrueFalseRadioState(answer) {
     angular.forEach(vm.files, function (a) {
        if (a.IsMyChoice !== answer.IsMyChoice) {
            a.IsMyChoice = false;
        }
     });
 };

 vm.setTrueFalseRadioState = setTrueFalseRadioState;
```

#### html:

*Notice, I use "ng-change" and "get" for binding to the scope due to the **controllerAs** syntax in the controller*

```
<input type="radio"
           id="isChoice_{{$index + 1}}"
           name="response"
           ng-value="{{$index + 1}}"
           ng-required="!file.IsMyChoice"
           ng-change="get.setTrueFalseRadioState(file)"
           data-ng-model="file.IsMyChoice" />
```

Comment: I discovered that if you want to send the object data to the backend server, you need to set the ng-value to its index `<input type="radio"
           id="isChoice_{{$index + 1}}"
           name="response"
           ng-value="{{$index + 1}}"
           ng-required="!file.IsMyChoice"
           ng-change="get.setTrueFalseRadioState(file)"
           data-ng-model="file.IsMyChoice" />` and the use javascript to check the values like: `if (file.IsMyChoice !== undefined) {
                file.IsMyChoice !== false ? file.IsMyChoice = 'true' : file.IsMyChoice = 'false';
            }`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be expecting results differently than AngularJS actually works. From your description of your problem you allude to thinking answer.is_correct will not change. In reality answer.is_correct is changing every time a radio button is selected.

> anwser.is_correct == false when ng-value="false" is checked and answer.is_correction == true when ng-value="true" is checked. This is the expected result of ng-model

To validate how this is working visit the [AngularJS Docs on ng-value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) and the example there showing you how the ng-model is applied when selecting a radio button.

You will need to do some backend coding against a ng-click function to determine if the right answer was selected or not.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm still relatively new at Angular, and I didn't really outline the question accurately. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe only a question should know about a correct answer.
You can have n answers, and if n.id = question.answer, then you have a match.